# Problem in binary file

Tags: linux, eclipse

I have downloaded [Eclipse IDE for J2EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php), Linux version.

When I run the binary file, it is not giving any error but Eclipse is not opening.
Do you have any elements I should check to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The condition for Eclipse to at least launch a session is to find Java.
You will find  all the details in the [launcher help page](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/launcher.html):

#### No -vm specified

> When no `-vm` is specified, the launcher looks for a virtual machine:
>
> - first in a jre directory in the root of eclipse
> - and then on the search path.
>
> If java is found in either location, then the launcher looks for a jvm shared library (`jvm.dll` on Windows, `libjvm.so` on *nix platforms) relative to that java executable.
>
> - If a jvm shared library is found the launcher loads it and uses the JNI invocation API to start the vm.
> - If no jvm shared library is found, the launcher executes the java launcher to start the vm in a new process.

So make sure:

- you do have a jvm installed in the search path,
- and that it is with the same architecture than the Eclipse J2EE you have downloaded:
  a 32-bits JVM should be used with a 32-bits Eclipse, a 64-bits JVM with a 64-bits Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use ubuntu? you can install eclipse by software management, i.e. Synaptic Package Manager for gnome, kpackagekit for kde.

Using this kind of way of installing fits the most seamless demand between software and Linux distribution, therefore, it can avoid various weird problems that can't be easily troubleshooted.

Perhaps other modern desktop version of linux also provides such kind of simple way to install software. I am not sure. Do try your luck.